# Finding if UpperCase of a value exists in a list of strings

Tags: c#

I have something like this:

```
string configKeys = "othewr|RDX|MDX";
```

and wrote a code like this to see if value "OTHER" exists in that list

```
List<string> values = configKeys.Split('|').ToList();
var b = values.Find(item => item.Trim().ToUpper() == "OTHER").FirstOrDefault();
```

but for example because I have typed it wrong "**othewr**" so it crashes, but  just want it to tell me if it exists or not as a `boolean`.  How can I change the code to do that and not crash?

Comment: If you want help fixing your code that "crashes", you need to a) show the full code so others can look at it and b) explain what you expect it to do and what it actually does (i.e. **how** it "crashes"). If your code actually is irrelevant and you just want the answer to _"How can I case-insensitively search a string's presence in a pipe-character separated list of strings"_, then I'd suggest searching. Also, I did not ask what you tried to solve your original problem (which is writing this code that does not work); I asked what you tried to get this code to work.

Comment: Perhaps try Exists instead of Find?

Comment: @CodeCaster, did someone make you angry? You marked the question as a duplicate of the question that is related to this one by no means.

Comment: @Giorgi if you'd follow the comments a bit, which I'm sure you did, you'll realise that OP does not want help getting their code fixed, they want their question title answered - which the duplicate does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Any`. If the predicate evaluates for at least one value in the collection it returns `true`, else `false`:

```
var b = values.Any(item => item.Trim().ToUpper() == "OTHER");
```

Comment: Something fish, something fire. Explain why.

Comment: @CodeCaster, didn't get you...

Comment: OP has some code that does not work. Instead of throwing fixed code at them (giving them a fish, or setting them on fire), explain what they did wrong and how to fix _that_ (teaching them to fish or make fire).

Comment: Wasn't this the OP's comment `I know why it crashes, I didn't ask why my code crashes! `? Did I miss something?